# anyone face this issue in django?

Tags: python, django, django-forms

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VfjMD.png)

when i created a employee form and view the form it show like as image.

```
<tr>
<td>{{ form.employee_name.label }}</td>
<td>{{ record.employee_name }}</td>
</tr>
 <tr>
<td>{{ form.dob.label }}</td>
<td>{{ record.dob }}</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>{{ form.age.label }}</td>
<td>{{ form.age }}</td>
</tr>
```

only age field show like  this, i review all  my code , it didnt find and issue, if face same issue please help me

Comment: Please share the relevant model and (Django) form.

Comment: Please [edit] the question with a more *descriptive title*. Currently the title does not make it very clear what the issue is about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use `{{ record.employee_name }}` here, so you don't render the form field, you just render the value for that `record`.

You thus implement this as:

```
<tr>
    <td>{{ form.employee_name.label }}</td>
    <td>{{ form.employee_name }}</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>{{ form.dob.label }}</td>
    <td>{{ form.dob }}</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>{{ form.age.label }}</td>
    <td>{{ form.age }}</td>
</tr>
```

---

> **Note**: You currently don't seem to render the *errors* of your form. You render the field specific ones with `{{ form.dob.errors }}` and errors not specific to a field with `{{ form.non_field_errors }}`. For more information, see the [*Rendering fields manually* section of the documentation <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/forms/#rendering-fields-manually).